# How to create a data model using Go's dataStore?

Tags: google-app-engine, database-design, go, data-modeling

I've created a series of structs based on the way I would create tables in mySQL:

```
type User struct {
    UserID      int
    Email       string
    Password    string
    DateCreated time.Time
}

type Device struct {
    DeviceID      int
    Udid          string
    DateCreated   time.Time
    DateUpdated   time.Time
    IntLoginTotal int
}

type DeviceInfo struct {
    DeviceID       int
    DeviceName     string
    Model          string
    LocalizedModel string
    SystemName     string
    SystemVersion  string
    Locale         string
    Language       string
    DateCreated    time.Time
}
```

However, I have the impression that I will not be able to make requests like this, and instead I need to create a single struct that can contain an array of multiple devices (each containing an array of multiple device info records).

What is the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: Why not []Device and []DeviceInfo?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, just set the "Kind" as the name of the struct.

From the docs:

```
func NewKey(c appengine.Context, kind, stringID string, intID int64, parent *Key) *Key
```

> NewKey creates a new key. kind cannot be empty. Either one or both of
>   stringID and intID must be zero. If both are zero, the key returned is
>   incomplete. parent must either be a complete key or nil.

For example to save a User.

```
c := appengine.NewContext(r)
u := &User{UserID: userid, Email: email, Password: password, DateCreated: datecreated}
k := datastore.NewKey(c, "User", u.UserID, 0, nil)
e := p
_, err := datastore.Put(c, k, e)
```

Follow the same logic to save a different struct type.

To load a user:

```
c := appengine.NewContext(r)

k := datastore.NewKey(c, "User", userid, 0, nil)
e := new(User)

_, err := datastore.Get(c, k, e)
```